# R if statement with condition >1 length error

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to run an if statement, where I want to run something IF any of 23 values is below a certain value.

```
   test.df<-as.data.frame(c(1:50))
   if (test.df[,c(27:50)] <30){ print("hi")}
```

I get the error that the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. Which is true... Does anyone know how I can test this if statement for 23 values, whithout having to type them one by one?

Thanks!

Comment: See `help("any")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
 if (any(test.df[,c(27:50)] <30)){ print("hi")}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the functions `all` or `any`, `isTRUE` and in newer versions of R, `isFALSE`, where the latter two to some degree takes care of fringe cases of `NULL`s and `NA`s.

For your example:

```
if (all(test.df[,c(27:50)] <30)) { 
  print("hi")
}
```